# Java stop sound when another sound is starting to play

Tags: java, javax

I'm Trying to make java game and now I'm implementing music to the game. Problem is if music is playing and sound is starting to play then I want to stop music.

**Current Code**

```
Clip clip;

public void playSound(File sound) {
    try {
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(sound));
        clip.start();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error with playing sound.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void stopSound() {
    if(clip == null) return;
    clip.stop();
}
```

But if I call stopSound method then sound never get's stopped.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Does "clip" exists in `stopSound()` context? To me, appears that you are instantiating "clip" object only inside `playSound` function.

Comment: I forgot to update.(i dint copy all needed code)

Comment: you are hiding your instance variable `clip` inside `try block` with `local variable clip`. replace `Clip clip=AudioSyste.getClip()` with `clip=AudioSyste.getClip()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope of `clip` is the problem. The `clip` object defined in `playSound` is unknown to `stopSound`.

If your object contain a `clip` attribute, try to change the first line of `playSound` to:

```
clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
```